# Nodemon stuck at "restarting due to changes..." and won't restart the server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have a pretty basic nodemon configuration. I'm fixing this legacy node 7 project that I inherited and trying to make the development process a little bit painful. First thing first, a proper restart-and-transpile process (since it's built using ES6 modules syntax).

This is my folder structure:

```
- src
  |- index.js
- dist
  |- index.js
- index.js
- nodemon.js
```

I run nodemon as `"start:dev": "nodemon index.js"`

Here's it's content:

```
// index.js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('./dist/index.js');
} else {
  require('babel-register')({});
  require('babel-polyfill');
  require('./src/index.js');
}
```

The idea is that the code is transpiled on runtime, so that I don't have to **stop server, re-transpile, start server** manually, as I have been doing before.

Last but not least, nodemon config

```
// nodemon.js
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js json"
}
```

I took this setup from [MERN](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter), and I think it should work. However, when I made a change and save, it goes:

```
[nodemon] files triggering change check: src/index.js
[nodemon] matched rule: /Users/me/project/path/src/**/*
[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] src/index.js

(stuck here. it never restarts)
```

I've been checking the code, and the only thing that I'm unfamiliar with, that maybe be causing it I can think of would be a `child_process.execFileSync()` call, that will call a java tool; and a connection pool with `mysql.createPool()` (`mysql` package).

Tried both in Node 7.5 and Node 8.9. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: it's a long shot, but did you ever find a solution to this?  i'm having the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992086/nodemon-restarts-but-saved-changes-to-index-js-not-reflected-in-output).

Answer (score 12):

I am using window 10, and I faced this issue after I accidentally removed my %PATH% variable. Try adding these three paths if it is the case:

> C:\Windows; C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;

Comment: Well I did the same mess and this helped me fix it!
10x

Comment: the Path should START with this(it didn't work for me when I paste it at the end of Path): %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Answer (score 7):

I was using windows 10, and I faced the same isuue. I used the supervisor instead of nodemon and it's working perfectly.

Run the below command :

`npm install supervisor -g`

`supervisor src/index.js`

Answer (score 6):

Add the below path in the environment variable. It will solve your problem.
**%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem;**

Answer (score 5):

For those who still do not have an answer, I reinstall an older version and it works

like "npm i -g nodemon@1.19.0"

Answer (score 4):

I was using windows 10, and I faced the same issue. I used the supervisor instead of nodemon and it started working fine for me.

Run the below command :

```
npm install supervisor
```

and in package.json add these below lines of code in the scripts key

```
"scripts": {"start": "supervisor app.js"}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, I tried every solution on the web to fix nodemon, looks like nodemon is a no go anymore for windows users, this is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Use below two commands:

```sh
npm install supervisor -g
supervisor src/index.js
```

Comment: It'd be valuable to add an explanation of what `node-supervisor` is and why it solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue before. I did the following things and it did work for me.

1. `npm start run:dev`
2. `nodemon npm start run:dev`

what is does is first i started server normally and then i used nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

type :  ps aux | grep node
or ps aux | grep port(e.g 3000)

and find the process copy its processId
then type in terminal 
kill -KILL processId

it will stop your process by force 
than again start server

Answer (score 0):

Try executing

```
npm -g uninstall nodemon
```

then

```
npm -g install nodemon
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you place your code in location without write permission.
(Especially who put on Desktop)
If no, please move the folder to other place with write permission.
Or change the folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

By default, nodemon looks for the .js file.
And due to the link of other extn files with your index.js file, it couldn't restart.

> node index.js -e js,hbs,html

You can mention all the extensions which are linked with your index.js file

Hope it works for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is now considered to be in stale situation.So its alternative npm package  supervisor can be installed globally by *npm i supervisor -g* and be used as *supervisor filename.js*

Answer (score 0):

go to my computer's properties, click on system protection then click on advanced then click on Environment variables .
There Two types of Variables. user variable and system variable.
in system variable click on path then click on edit ,click on new (add three variables)
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System\Wbem
then click ok .Rerun your cmd then run .it works

Answer (score 0):

Supervisior is an alternative for nodemon.  It worked for me

1. npm i supervisior -g
2. supervisior app.js

Answer (score 0):

In The `Package.Json` File Add Start Script As

```
"nodemon": "nodemon dev-server.js"
```

and  Start The Server As

```
npm run nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

When I using the latest version of nodeJS, it won't work.
But when I change back to 10.15.0, it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure nodemon isn't watching a file that you are writing to when the server starts up. You can set nodemon to ignore that (those) file(s) using the `--ignore` flag

for example

```
nodemon index.js --ignore 'something/*.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 update for windows 10**

Go to This Pc -> properties -> Advance System Settings -> Environment variable -> User Variables.

Double click 'path' and create 'New'. Then add this path

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

**Note:** Make sure to close and restart your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me;

Delete these directories; `C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/npm` and `C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache` and re-installed global npm modules.

Sheers!!

Answer (score -1):

open cmd as administrator and write nodemon [namefile.js]